# Django date-based ArchiveView with ForeignKey date_field

Tags: django, django-views

I have Django models describing Places and Visits to those Places on a particular day:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    # ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Visit(models.Model):
    # ...
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place', blank=False)
    visit_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
```

I want to display all the Places visited in a year, so I've tried using `YearArchiveView` with a `date_field` spanning the relationship with Visits:

```
from django.views.generic import YearArchiveView
from myapp.models import Place

class PlaceYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    date_field = 'visit__visit_date'
    model = Place
```

However, this gets me "Place has no field named 'visit__visit_date'".

What's the simplest way to have this view use a queryset that's like this (assuming `d1` and `d2` are the first and last days of the year in question):

```
Place.objects.filter(visit__visit_date__gte=d1, visit__visit_date__lte=d2).distinct()
```

I could use a standard `ListView` and write my own `get_queryset()` method but if I can base this on `YearArchiveView` that seems better.

Comment: Does `placeset__visit__visit_date` work?

Comment: No, similar result. I haven't seen `placeset__` style in a filter before.

Comment: Try also: `Place.objects.filter(visit__visit_date__year=2016).distinct()`

Comment: I didn't know, or had forgotten, about `__year`, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` should be enough for your needs, since `YearArchiveView` is usually used for date hierarchies, and in your case, the next level is `Place`.

If you do want to use `YearArchiveView`, you will need to... mmm... play with it a bit. Below are two options.

Assuming the following Visit model (after some small changes):

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='visits')
    date = models.DateField()
```

Option 1: Use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag:

`views.py`:

```
class PlaceYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    date_field = 'date'
    model = models.Visit
    make_object_list = True
    ordering = ('place', 'date')
```

`visit_archive_year.html`:

```
<h1>{{ year.year }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% regroup object_list by place as grouped %}
    {% for group in grouped %}
        <li>
            {{ group.grouper.name }}
            ({% for visit in group.list %}{{ visit.date }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Option 2: modifying `get_dated_items()'

`views.py`:

```
class PlaceYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    date_field = 'date'
    make_object_list = True
    model = models.Visit
    ordering = 'place'

    def get_dated_items(self):
        items, qs, info = super().get_dated_items()
        return items, qs.distinct('place'), info
```

`visit_archive_year.html`:

```
<h1>{{ year.year }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for v in object_list %}
        <li>@{{ v.date }}: {{ v.place.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this @Udi. These both work out OK as slightly different ways for doing what I want. I want to use `YearArchiveView` so that I have the `next_year`, `previous_year`, etc values in the context. I'd completely overlooked `make_object_list` too, which is pretty crucial!